# Error: illegal escape character - when trying to create a path

Tags: java, windows, path

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn how to create a path. Below is the code I wrote:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path p1 = Paths.get("C:\Users\Justin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication\xanadu1.txt");
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code, the IDE output error:

```
Illegal escape character.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Or use a Unix path with a forward slash, it works fine on Windows.

Comment: @dzjustinli Take a look at my solution below.

Comment: Forward slashes should be avoided.  They work under some circumstances, but not always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certain characters have special meaning when used in a String in Java (and many other languages).

A backward slash `\` can be used to escape a character. Some valid escape characters in Java are like `\t` for ***tabs*** and `\n` for ***newlines***.

Hence if you use only a single `\`. The compiler will assume that you are trying to create an escape sequence for:

```
\U, \J, \D, \N, \x
```

and these escape sequences do not exist, hence giving you the error.

---

If you are using `\` you have to escape it to `\\`.

But if you use `/` a forward slash, you don't have to.

So you can have a path like this:

```
"C:\\Users\\Justin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication\\xanadu1.txt"
```

**or** like this:

```
"C:/Users/Justin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication/xanadu1.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @Satya said you have to use double backward slashes `\\`.
A single `\` starts a so called escape sequence to express several special (non-printable) characters.

You can find more about escape sequences [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)